# Explain the interaction of this lambda function, sting variable, and another function in Tkinter

Tags: python, lambda, tkinter

I don't understand how this lambda function is being used to update the label that appears in this tkinter frame when the btn_del button is pressed. Any help?

```
# string variable used in the label
cadelVar = StringVar()

# buttons and labels
btn_del = ttk.Button(frame, text='Delineate!', underline=0,
                     command=lambda v=cadelVar: self._delineate(v))
lbl_del = ttk.Label(frame, textvariable=cadelVar, name='delineate')

# positioning and resizing
btn_del.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=(2,4))
lbel_del.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=(2,4))

# function that updates the label to say 'delineating....'
def _delineate(self, v):
    v.set('Delineating....')
    self.update()
```

Comment: Is there a specific part of that that doesn't make sense to you, or the whole thing?

Comment: Mainly the whole thing....but if I understood the lambda, I think I have enough pieces to work the rest out.

Comment: So, `lambda` functions?

Comment: The v=CadelVar part is the confusing part. The button command is set to a lambda function, and within that lambda function the cadelVar is updated to 'Delineating....' and the frame is refreshed to show the label again, now with the textvariable in the label set to an updated cadelVar. But I don't really understand the inner workings....

Comment: `lambda` functions, then. I suggest you Google that term, along with comparisons between `lambda` functions and ordinary functions.

Comment: I am and continue to...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you have to realize is that the `Button` widget takes a function with **zero** arguments in the `commmand` field.

Now, remember that you can set default values the arguments of functions that you create, and then you can call the function without those arguments. Like this:

```
def calc(x=1):
    return 2*x
```

If you run `calc(5)`, you will get `10` as answer. But if you just call `calc()`, `x` will assume it's default value, `1`, and you will get `2` as output.

The `lambda` function returns a function. If I were to define the previous mentioned calc function, I would have to do like this:

```
calc = lambda x=1: 2*x
```

By now you should have realized what that `lambda` function in your example means. It's returning a function that take an argument `v` defaulted as the value of `cadelVar`. Since, as mentioned, the `command` field of a button takes zero arguments, `v` will me made equal `cadelVar`. Therefore, `self_delineate(v)` will be called with `cadelVar` as it's argument.

It's a nice way of saving lines of code.

Comment: So, the (default) argument (`v`) for the lambda function is being set to `cadelVar` - in effect the variable `v` is being initialized to `cadelVar`.  `v` is then passed to the `_delineate` function where is is reset to be 'Delineating...'.  Since `v` at this point is equal to the string variable `cadelVar` , which is the `textvariable` for `lbl_del`, calling self.update updates the entire frame and re-displays the label `lbl_del` with the new value for `cadelVar`.  Is this the total workflow?  I am surprised that a variable type (VarString) can be passed to a function thru lambda...

Comment: Yes, that's the total workflow.

But you're last statement seems confuse. `cadelVar` does not hold a 'variable type'. It holds an object returned by the `StringVar()` function, which has the `set` method defined. This object is passed to the `_delineate()` function, in which it's `set` method is called.

Comment: Yep, get it.  Now that I get it, it all seems over complicated when this seems to work just as well:  `lambda: self._delineate(del_Var)`

Comment: @traggatmot: yes, it works just as well _in this particular case_ In fact, you don't need lambda at all here. Since your function only ever acts upon the one object (`cadelVar`) you can just access it directly as a global variable. Where the lambda and argument passing is necessary is when you're creating multiple widgets that all must act on different values or objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
ttk.Button(frame, text='Delineate!', underline=0,
                 command=lambda v=cadelVar: self._delineate(v))
```

command option takes call back handler function. 
lambda return a function object, so command option get what is needed. 
Try to execute these two statements-

```
command=lambda v=cadelVar: self._delineate(v)
type(command)
```